# Upgrade Macbook Pro Retina A1502 SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I have an Early 2015 Macbook Pro Retina with a 128Gb SSD and 8Gb of RAM. I know I can't upgrade the RAM but I can upgrade the SSD. Will an Apple Store upgrade my SSD if I take my Macbook to them? Is it possible to know how much will it cost? Or maybe exchange my Mac for another one (same model) with a 512Gb SSD paying the difference?

I have seen [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AINK26K) SSD in Amazon that should work for my Mac but if possible I prefer an official Apple Store to do the replacement. I'm asking because I will be traveling to NY and in my country they won't upgrade the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I've heard Apple uses proprietary firmware on their SSDs (I could be wrong), however OWC does make SSDs specifically for the 2015 Retina MacBook Pro, so it appears they've figured out how to make replacements. Here's the [link](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/macbook-pro-retina-display/2013-2014-2015). I'm not affiliated with them, but have bought RAM and a replacement Mac battery from them, both of which work great.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't do upgrades or upgrade exchanges. OWC is the only option AFAIK. They have a good reputation and you can review the install video to see if you are comfortable with it. If you don't buy the kit, you should at least order the Torx T5 and Pentalobe T5 screwdrivers needed to do the upgrade.

Make sure to double-check the model number as explained on the OWC page.